# How to add SVG as background image in Django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Pls how can I add SVG as background image in Django

I have tried and it's not working

I added the svg in this format `url("image.svg")` but nothing is showing.

Comment: Please add your template code and your folder structure for the project.

Answer (score 0):

#### you can load image form static like this in Django

`````
<body style="background-image: url('/static/images/test_image.svg');">
    
    ``` code here ````
    
</body>
`````